# how to search a pattern in a file which ends with $

Tags: regex, unix

I am trying to list out all the files which does not have the following pattern in it

- a) line should contain `$Id` in it and
- b) the same line should also end with `$`

For example :

```
#$Id abcd 2019 Exp $

# $Id abcd 03930 9:55 a.pm $
```

I am able to meet the first condition i.e (a) but not the second one (b)

I am using the following command :

```
find . -type f | xargs grep -H -c '$Id' | grep 0$ | cut -d':' -f1
```

Please help me to meet the second condition i.e (b) alongwith the (a). How should i modify the `grep` command to match the `$` at the end of the line as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to escape the special characters, since `$` is the symbol for end of line.

```
$
```

Becomes:

```
\$
```

You could also use the beginning line character:

```
^\$
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `-c` which breaks the output. Instead, use just `-H` and `-exec` like this:

So if you want to print "those files that have line containing $Id but missing '$' at the end in that same line", then this can make:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -H '$Id' {} \; | grep -v "\$$" | cut -d: -f1
```

Also, note "ends with $" can be checked with `\$$`: `\$` to escape the `$` itself and the second `$` to match end of line.

#### Test

```
$ cat f1
#$Id abcd 2019 Exp $
# $Id abcd 03930 9:55 a.pm $
$ cat f2
#$Id abcd 2019 Exp a
# $Id abcd 03930 9:55 a.pm b
$ find . -type f -exec grep -H '$Id' {} \; | grep -v "\$$" | cut -d: -f1
./f2
./f2
```

Comment: your command is returning me those files which has line containing $Id and '$' at the end. But I want files which has line containing $Id but missing '$' at the end in that same line.

Comment: @AbhijitGhosh I see... check update, I did not understand the requirement properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine both `grep` into one:

```
grep -iE '\$id.*[^$]$'
```

Comment: your command is returning me those files which has line containing $Id and '$' at the end. But I want files which has line containing $Id but missing '$' at the end in that same line.

Comment: oh ok got it, then you need `grep -iE '\$id.*[^$]$'` (edited now)

Answer (score 0):

You can make this way simpler just by doing:

```
find . -type -f -exec grep '\$Id.*\$$' {} \;
```

You don't need the `-H` argument if you're just going to split on the `:` and disregard that on the left hand side anyway.

Also, using the `-exec` argument to `find` means you don't actually have to pipe the results to anything else.